# Performance of regex in java vs perl. 8 times slower

Tags: java, regex, perl

I have to rewrite some legacy perl application in java. 
This app does a lot of text processing. 
   But java regular expressions are almost 6-8 times slower than perl. 
How can I optimize the performance of this

Java code takes 26s to replace string 50k times 
Perl code takes 4s

For the sake of replicating the scenario I have hosted the string on an online file. In my real use case this string would come from an input queue

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class RegexT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //RegexTest r = new RegexTest();
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("${ TO }", "rcpt");
        m.put("${ MESSAGE_ID }", "37");
        m.put("${ ID }", "40");
        m.put("${ UNIQID }", "cff47534-fe6b-c45a-7058-8301adf1b97");
        m.put("${ XOR }", "abcdef");

        System.out.println(m);

        String rx = "(\\$\\{[^}]+\\})";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
        String s = readStringFromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramprasadp/hostedtexfiles/master/msg2.txt");
        //        System.out.println(s); System.exit(0);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            Matcher mat = p.matcher(s);

            while (mat.find()) {
                String repString = m.get(mat.group(1));
                if (repString != null) {
                    mat.appendReplacement(sb, repString);
                }
            }
            mat.appendTail(sb);
        }

        long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Time taken in ms = "+ timeTaken);

    }

    public static String readStringFromURL(String requestURL) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new URL(requestURL).openStream(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())) {
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
            return scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "No file";
        }
    }


}
```

And same logic in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday tv_interval );
use strict;
my %data;

$data{'TO'} = "rcpt";
$data{'MESSAGE_ID'} = "37";
$data{'ID'} = "7";
$data{'UNIQID'} = "cff47534-fe6b-c45a-7058-8301adf1b97";
$data{'XOR'} = "abcdef";


#Get the content
my $msg_string = `wget -q -O - http://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramprasadp/hostedtexfiles/master/msg2.txt`;

my $start = [gettimeofday];
for (my $j=0;$j<50000; $j++) {
    my $tmp_string = $msg_string;
    $tmp_string =~ s/\$\{ ([\w_]+) \}/$data{$1}/g;
}
print "Time taken in ms is " . 1000 * tv_interval ( $start )."\n";
```

Comment: Your Parl regex can be written as `\$\{ (\w+) \}`. Actually, why didn't you use the same to test in Java? Try with `"\\$\\{ (\\w+) }"`. However, the answer is most probably "you can't expect the same performance from different regex implementations".

Comment: But I can not afford this. Is there a perl style implementation in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a more in-depth benchmark or profiling is done on this code, it's hard to impute this low performance solely to the Regex implementation (although I tend to -speculatively- agree with you...).

So, I tried this exact code, it took **14 seconds** to run on my machine. I tried to run it in parallel, and this reduced it **from 14 to 3 seconds**:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i+1).limit(50000).parallel().forEach((i) -> {

    Matcher mat = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (mat.find()) {
        String repString = m.get(mat.group(1));
        if (repString != null) {
            mat.appendReplacement(sb, repString);
        }
    }
    mat.appendTail(sb);
});
```

Now, I suppose that your exact problem isn't particularly linked to the fact that code is running sequentially or not (it's unlikely that your real-world application will do this 50000 find/replace exercise on a single string), but this at least leads to other aspects not mentioned in your question (or even not considered at all). Otherwise, it also tells you that if this is something used this intensively, you'd better run it in parallel. In other words, this answers the "How can I optimize the performance of this" question...

You'd probably have to compare the results of *single executions* with as little as possible involvement of other classes to minimize the effect of other factors, but comparing performance across languages will surely remain challenging.

---

**An alternative** you could consider is **Groovy's template engine**, which performs better than both (assuming the template is reused - which is very possible to do). This is particularly good in your case, because you wouldn't need to change the placeholders in your template text.

```
Map<String, String> binding = new HashMap<>();
binding.put("TO", "rcpt");
binding.put("MESSAGE_ID", "37");
binding.put("ID", "40");
binding.put("UNIQID", "cff47534-fe6b-c45a-7058-8301adf1b97");
binding.put("XO", "abcdef");
binding.put("XOR", "abcdef");

String text  = s;
groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine();
Template template = engine.createTemplate(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        template.make(binding).toString();
    }

    long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Time taken in ms = "+ timeTaken);
}
```

The above Groovy version completes in **3.182 seconds**; while its parallel version (same stream mechanism) completes in **2.313 seconds**

You can find out more about groovy templates [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html)

Comment: Groovy seems to work for me. 
Though I have to try various cases before really concluding. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple substring handling gets it down to 12-13s:

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        String tmpS = s;
        for (Entry<String, String> ms : m.entrySet()) {
            int index = -1;
            while ((index = tmpS.indexOf(ms.getKey())) >= 0) {
                tmpS = tmpS.substring(0, index) + ms.getValue() + tmpS.substring(index + ms.getKey().length());
            }
        }
    }
```

Since you know that there is exacly one match for each tag, you can optimize it a bit, bringing execution time down to 7.5s:

```
        for (Entry<String, String> ms : m.entrySet()) {
            int index = tmpS.indexOf(ms.getKey());
            tmpS = tmpS.substring(0, index) + ms.getValue() + tmpS.substring(index + ms.getKey().length());
        }
```

Not quite Perl speed, but still 4x faster than the Java regexp approach.

And if your really are looking to save a few seconds, you can use the fact that your tags appear in the beginning of the message. I don't know if that's always the case, but it is a fair guess. This takes only 2.5s:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        int i1 = s.lastIndexOf("}") + 1;
        String tmpS = s.substring(0, i1);
        for (Entry<String, String> ms : m.entrySet()) {
            int i2 = tmpS.indexOf(ms.getKey());
            tmpS = tmpS.substring(0, i2) + ms.getValue() + tmpS.substring(i2 + ms.getKey().length());
        }
        String result = tmpS + s.substring(i1);
    }
```

Now the Java implementation is faster than the original Perl implementation.

I also compbined my `s.lastIndexOf("}")` trick with your original `regexp` approach and then it **only took 2.3s.** So this would be my recommendation, given that you can assume that your tags are always in the beginning of the string.